# Using props how to update the data in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**component**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <b>Vuejs dynamic routing</b>
    <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
      <b>{{ item.id }}.</b> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <router-link
        @update="updateValue"
        :to="{ name: 'UserWithID', params: { id: item.id, items: items } }"
      >
        {{ item.val }}{{ item.kk }}
      </router-link>
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br />

    {{ $route.params.id }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Using props how to update the data in Vuejs?

I have two components called, helloworld, User. And i have mocked the data inside of helloworld.vue. Now using the props the want to get he data inside of the User component and preform the update operation . When trying to preform the logic.

Where onclick of button. it is going to method, But not updating the logic

I have kept console. inside method. and its printing. but logic not updating

Comment: Hey @Sundar, you are getting the warning and error because In HelloWorld component you are switching components using router link. And the User component requires the items props which is not being passed.

Comment: { required: true, default: () => {}, } only means that a value must be passed not that it is being passed.

Comment: please see if this solves your problem.
https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-ptolemy-35bsb?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue.

Comment: Yes, it was just to show how to clear the error you were getting. What functionality do you want the code to achieve can you please explain a little?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you are getting errors in the console as you are not passing the items as props to the User component and it is a required field in the User component.

And for the second point, you should store data in a separate file not in the main component so the items array doesn't get initialized again when the parent component is rendered again. The best option would be a global store(vuex) for sake of simplicity, it is done a separate file for now just as an example.

Here is a sample sandbox hope it helps:

https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-ptolemy-35bsb?file=/src/components/User.vue

Comment: As router link is being used to switch between components. So somehow we have to make data in sync with the updated data from User component which is not possible without any external source as we can not listen for external event via emit with router link.